# Interact with Scripts from Console

Tags: screeps

Is there any way to call a module or function from the console?  For example a module that creates worker creeps, called from the console with my_module.add_creep?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the given example, use `require('my_module').add_creep();`
The require function returns whatever is assigned to module.exports in that module.

@cho: require doesn't have to return a function. It rather returns a function because the module contains a function. If the module assigns as follow `module.export = {test: 'test'}`, follow snippet `require('that_module')` will return `{test: 'test'}` etc...

Note: Not sure if others have this issue, but sometimes the console isn't returning a result at all... <strike>In that case, try reloading the page.</strike> Just make sure the game isn't pauzed while executing commands...

Answer (score 4):

I just figured this out today. But there is a nice way to access your methods from the console

Just import your methods to the Game object (in your script)

```
Game.creepManager = require('CreepManager');
```

you can now use the console by typing

```
Game.creepManager.yourFunctionHere();
```

Comment: @Andrew you should assign the thing you want accessible from Game in the game loop (as Game appears to get overwritten every tick with a new state, so you have to re-add your property)

Answer (score 2):

Others have mentioned the use of require and assigning to Game, but you can also create new top level commands and objects by assigning to global.

Main loop:

```
global.rebuildMemory = () => console.log('Memory rebuilt.');
global.Commands = require('consoleCommands');
```

Then from the console:

```
rebuildMemory();
Commands.printRoomReport('W3N4');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to call the lodash module from the console by calling it like this `require('lodash').pluck(characters, 'name')`. Not sure if it works with user created modules.

Answer (score 0):

The `require` function returns a function so you can call it direclty in the console like this:

```
require('harvester')(Game.creeps.harvester1);
```